# Modify x-axis labels of C3 plot from R

Tags: r, c3.js

Using an R script, I would like to modify the x-axis labels of a plot created with the c3 package.

From the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/c3/c3.pdf), under xAxis it states that the `categories` argument is a character vector and, "Can be used to modify axis labels. Not needed if already defined in data"

In Javascript, it certainly looks possible [here](https://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html).

Here is my failed attempt to modify the x-axis labels.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("c3")

data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,2),
           b=c(2,3,1,5)) %>%
  c3() %>%
  xAxis(categories = c("A", "B",  "C"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default of `xAxis` `type = 'indexed'` found in the help file.

```
type    character on of 'indexed', 'timeseries' or 'category'
```

So if you use `type="category"` it should work:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("c3")

data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,2),
           b=c(2,3,1,5)) %>%
  c3() %>%
  xAxis(type="category",categories = c("A", "B",  "C"))
```

[image]

So now the x axis has A, B, and C, but ends with 3 because it was indexed as 0, 1, 2, 3 and you only supplied 3 categories (A, B, C), so it kept its last category as 3